# Make contingency table from rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregation, contingency

I have a covid data frame with 376 columns, 7 rows with covid infection numbers of 376 different days in 7 countries. I've matched them different severity categories and now I'm trying to make a contingency table containing the severity categories as columns and countries as rows. I've written a function and it works but I'm still wondering if there is a more elegant solution maybe including such a thing as a table() function with an aggregation for each row.

My code:

```
  severity <- function(x,countries){
    sev = c("Leicht","Mittel","Schwer")
    res=matrix(ncol=3,nrow=7)
    colnames(res) = sev
    rownames(res) = countries
    for (i in 1:nrow(x)){
      for (s in 1:length(sev)){
        res[i,s]=length(x2[i,x2[i,]==sev[s]])
      }
    }
    return(res)
}
r = severity(x2,covid_world2[,1]) #covid_world2 countains the countrynames, x2 the data with the categories
x = rbind(r,"Z" = colSums(r))
ctable=cbind(x,"S" = rowSums(x))
```

This is just an example of the first two rows in x2 (namely, representing the countries Canada,Germany)

[image]

```
dput(head(covid_world2[, 1:20]))
```

output is:

```
structure(list(Country = c("Canada", "France", "Germany", "Italy", 
"Japan", "United Kingdom"), X1_22_20 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1.58132191886678e-08, 
0), X1_23_20 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1.58132191886678e-08, 0), X1_24_20 = c(0, 
3.06403006266968e-08, 0, 0, 1.58132191886678e-08, 0), X1_25_20 = c(0, 
4.59604509400452e-08, 0, 0, 1.58132191886678e-08, 0), X1_26_20 = c(2.6495573093152e-08, 
4.59604509400452e-08, 0, 0, 3.16264383773357e-08, 0), X1_27_20 = c(2.6495573093152e-08, 
4.59604509400452e-08, 1.19354613321966e-08, 0, 3.16264383773357e-08, 
0), X1_28_20 = c(5.2991146186304e-08, 6.12806012533936e-08, 4.77418453287863e-08, 
0, 5.53462671603374e-08, 0), X1_29_20 = c(5.2991146186304e-08, 
7.6600751566742e-08, 4.77418453287863e-08, 0, 5.53462671603374e-08, 
0), X1_30_20 = c(5.2991146186304e-08, 7.6600751566742e-08, 4.77418453287863e-08, 
0, 8.69727055376731e-08, 0), X1_31_20 = c(1.05982292372608e-07, 
7.6600751566742e-08, 5.96773066609828e-08, 3.3078723093808e-08, 
1.18599143915009e-07, 2.94611506927399e-08), X02_01_2020 = c(1.05982292372608e-07, 
9.19209018800904e-08, 9.54836906575725e-08, 3.3078723093808e-08, 
1.58132191886678e-07, 2.94611506927399e-08), X02_02_2020 = c(1.05982292372608e-07, 
9.19209018800904e-08, 1.19354613321966e-07, 3.3078723093808e-08, 
1.58132191886678e-07, 2.94611506927399e-08), X02_03_2020 = c(1.05982292372608e-07, 
9.19209018800904e-08, 1.43225535986359e-07, 3.3078723093808e-08, 
1.58132191886678e-07, 1.1784460277096e-07), X02_04_2020 = c(1.05982292372608e-07, 
9.19209018800904e-08, 1.43225535986359e-07, 3.3078723093808e-08, 
1.73945411075346e-07, 1.1784460277096e-07), X02_05_2020 = c(1.3247786546576e-07, 
9.19209018800904e-08, 1.43225535986359e-07, 3.3078723093808e-08, 
1.8185202066968e-07, 1.3257517811733e-07), X02_06_2020 = c(1.3247786546576e-07, 
9.19209018800904e-08, 1.43225535986359e-07, 3.3078723093808e-08, 
1.8185202066968e-07, 1.3257517811733e-07), X02_07_2020 = c(1.85469011652064e-07, 
9.19209018800904e-08, 1.55160997318555e-07, 4.9618084640712e-08, 
1.8185202066968e-07, 1.3257517811733e-07), X02_08_2020 = c(1.85469011652064e-07, 
1.68521653446832e-07, 1.55160997318555e-07, 4.9618084640712e-08, 
1.89758630264014e-07, 1.9149747950281e-07), X02_09_2020 = c(1.85469011652064e-07, 
1.68521653446832e-07, 1.67096458650752e-07, 4.9618084640712e-08, 
1.89758630264014e-07, 2.06228054849179e-07)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Just wanted to note that in x2 the value are categorized as "Leicht" "Mittel" or "Schwer" regarding their range.

Comment: This output has been altered and so I cannot access the data. I understand you're probably concerned about the number of columns. So you could do `dput(head(covid_world2[, 1:20]))` to get the first 20 columns. This should be enough data to create a reproducible example.

Comment: Btw I used this function for categorizing:
`severeness <- function(v){
  for (i in 1:length(v)){
    if(v[i]< 0.01){
      v[i]="Leicht"
    }
    else if(v[i]>= 0.01 & v[i]<0.05 ){
      v[i]="Mittel"
    }
    else if(v[i]>0.05){
      v[i]="Schwer"
    }
  }
  return(v)
}
x2=apply(covid_world2[,-1],2,severeness) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

severity <- c("Leicht", "Mitte", "Schwer")
ranges <- c(0, 0.01, 0.05, Inf)

df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(across(starts_with("X"), ~cut(., ranges, right = F, labels = severity))) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -Country,
                      names_to = "Date",
                      values_to = "Severity") %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(across(2, ~ as.Date(., tryFormats = "X%m_%d_%y"))) %>% # can delete line
  tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols = Country,
                     names_from = Severity,
                     values_from = Severity,
                     values_fn = length)

 Country        Leicht
  <chr>           <int>
1 Canada             19
2 France             19
3 Germany            19
4 Italy              19
5 Japan              19
6 United Kingdom     19
```

---

**How it works**

1. `mutate` will apply the function `cut` across all columns that start with "X". Cut uses the provided ranges (excluding the upper bound) and labels values within those range with the appropriate label from the vector `severity`.

```
cut(0.01, range, right = F)
[1] [0.01,0.05)
Levels: [0,0.01) [0.01,0.05) [0.05,Inf)
```

You can see that 0.01 is included in the range `[0.01,0.05)` because the right bound is not inclusive due to `right = F`. Adding `label = severity` to this function will apply the proper label of `"Mitte"`

2. `tidyr::pivot_longer` will pivot all columns except `Country` to a long format. The column names will be stored in a new column called `Date`. The values of the columns after `mutate` will be stored in a new column called `Severity`.
3. The final `mutate` changes the column `Date` to a date vector. So `"X2_01_20"` becomes a date `2020-02-01`. Note: you can delete this pipe, if you only care about the tabulation done in the next step. I included it in case you needed to look at things by date.
4. `tidyr::pivot_wider` will count the severity values for each country